# Authorize.net AIM submission changes?

Tags: coldfusion, authorize.net, coldfusion-11

I have been hearing a lot about some new encryption needed for submitting transactions to Authorize.net but cannot find anything that explains it.

The AIM instructions for 2015 describe what I am already using except the post address has changed.

When I just submitted a transaction to the new address it was rejected.

Here is my code:

```
 <cflock timeout="30" throwontimeout="No" name="12345">
 <cfhttp url="https://secure.anetsgateway.net/gateway/transact.dll"  method="post">
<cfoutput>  
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="x_login" value="myclient12345">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="x_tran_key" value="myxtrankey12345">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="x_version" value="3.1">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="x_test_request" value="TRUE">
```

The "x_tran_key" and "x_login" are hard-coded in my submission page.

Can someone explain where the issue is and examples of what special encryption I need.

Comment: Hearing from who? If Authorize.Net didn't say it then it isn't true. Consult their documentation.

Comment: use the correct url : https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the wrong URL to talk to Authorize.Net. You should consult [the documentation](http://www.authorize.net/content/dam/authorize/documents/AIM_guide.pdf) for the correct URL and proper method for integrating.

I would also like to add that placing your transaction key in the form is not a very good idea. It should be treated like a password.

Comment: The Authorize,net URL is just for example as is the x_login and x_tran_key.

Comment: Do you mean the question contains a *different* URL than what you are are actually using in your code? There is no reason to obfuscate a public URL. Having said that, you did not answer [the question from the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35927982/authorize-net-aim-submission-changes#comment59516785_35927982): *"Hearing from who? If Authorize.Net didn't say it then it isn't true."*